# VBS Reopen already open Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm a newbie with vbs and trying to figure out how to reopen excel file.
I have like 100+ excels in one folder, where I need to open them one by one and run the macro.
It is working pretty well except for files, which are already open. I would like to reopen them and edit them.
Could you please advise how to do it?
Bellow is the code:

```
Const sRootFolder = "C:\test"

Dim oFSO, oFile ' File and Folder variables
Dim xlApp, xlBook, objWorkbook 

Start

Sub Start()
    Initialize
    ProcessFilesInFolder sRootFolder
    Finish
End Sub

Sub ProcessFilesInFolder(sFolder)
    ' Process the files in this folder
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
        If IsExcelFile(oFile) Then ProcessExcelFile oFile.Path
    Next
End Sub

Sub Initialize()
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   
End Sub

Sub Finish()
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlBook = Nothing 
    Set xlApp = Nothing    
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Function IsExcelFile(oFile)
    IsExcelFile = (InStr(1, oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile), "xls", vbTextCompare) > 0) And (Left(oFile.Name, 1) <> "~")
End Function

Sub ProcessExcelFile(sFileName)   
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFileName, 0, True) 
    Set objWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)     
    xlApp.Run "macro"

End Sub 

Sub Save()
xlBook.Save
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit


    WScript.Echo "Finished."
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to reopen and lose any changes made to the opened file or just make the already opened files active?

Comment: In case changes being lost are not a concern then just kill all the EXCEL.exe processes before creating your Automation Object.

Comment: yes i would like to just reopen the document and lose any changes made.

Comment: I've tried to add following two lines before Sub Start- `Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`
`oShell.Run "taskkill /im EXCEL.EXE", , True` and another taskkill line behind the End Sub. Unfortunately it doesn't work as it should.